# Putting my project in github repo

Tags: git, project

When I created my first project,I created a repo (say `project1`) on my `github account` and then cloned it in my machine. And then pushed to it whenever code in my machine was updated.

Now I created another project- say `project2` in my machine. Tested it, created local repo using `git init`. I want to push this project to github. For this purpose I created a `repo` on `github` named `project2`. It now has a `.gitignore` and `readme.md` files in it.

Now, how do I add my existing code to this? When I cd'd to my `project2` directory and tried `git push`, I get this error:

```
fatal: No destination configured to push to.
```

I tried `git push project2`

```
fatal: 'project2' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Please help me correct this error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the new repository as a remote:

```
git remote add project2 git@github.com:Nickname/project2.git
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to name the remote `origin` instead of `project2`. That way the default push and pull works without having to specify the remote.

Comment: Indeed, I recommend this. I wrote `origin` at the beggining, but changed it since he tried to do `git push project2`.

Comment: thanks ,my repo url is `https://github.com/myname/project2.git` .So,what is the Nickname I have to specify?

Comment: By *Nickname* I meant your Github username. Also, I recommend using the *git* protocol, it's faster than HTTPS.

Comment: I added the remote..when I pushed,I got this error ` To git@github.com:myname/project2.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myname/project2.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: That's because you have to pull the commits that are on the remote repo before you can push yours (you have a *.gitignore* and a *readme.md* there, remember?). Simply `git pull`, then `git push`. You can also `git push -f` to force the push and override the remote history, but use it with care!

Answer (score 8):

The steps are:

1. `cd project_directory`
2. `git init`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "your_commit_message"`
5. `git remote add origin https://github.com/[your_user_name]/[repo_name]`
6. `git push origin master`

Comment: Rockin'. I'm enough of a git-noob to need this help and an experienced enough dev that such a succinct answer saved me a great deal of time. Thanks, Keen.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the repository on your github homepage. When asked, do NOT choose to create a .gitignore and a README.md file.
2. At the bottom of the screen, command line instructions will appear explaining how to push your existing repository to the newly created repository on github:

   `git remote add origin git@github.com:[your_user_name]/[repo_name].git`

   `git push -u origin master`